# SSIS - Advanced Editor for ODBC Source - Input and Output properties does not save settings

Tags: sql-server, ssis, type-conversion

I am trying to change the DataType property for a column in an ODBC Source in a DTSX Package in SSIS via: SSIS - Advanced Editor for ODBC Source - Input and Output properties.

I change from Data Type: `currency [DT_CY]`
[image: Change Source]
To Data Type: `numeric [DT_NUMERIC]`
[image: Change Target]

Press OK but when I re-open the advanced editor the change is not preserved. Attached document with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter the data type via that dialogue box as the column meta data is set/refreshed by the source object.

In order to do this, you'd need to add a `data conversion` transformation in the data flow, alter the type there, and assign that newly created column to your destination object instead of the original column.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms140321(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks Jiggs Jedi, will pursue this.